# How can I combine multiple spreadsheets (cvs) into one master sheet using the terminal?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

If I want to merge / combine multiple spreadsheets into one master spread sheet, I can just manually add them in LibreOffice. However this becomes cumbersome when dealing with a large number of sheets (>50).

Is there any way to automatize this, giving a list of spreadsheets as inputs and merging them all in one step?

EDIT:

All spreadsheets are in the same format: Same number of columns and rows, and same names.

Comment: What is your desired output for these sheets? what is your CVS files schema?

Comment: can you provide more details about how you want them combined? do they all have the same column names and you are just adding to the end of the columns?  or are you adding new columns?

Comment: @Jeff They are all in exactly the same format. Only difference is the cell entries. They represent a n-dimensional spreadsheet, or a 2D spreadsheet with each cell having a length n vector